# Insulating stand-alone studio (shed)

Tags: insulation

I am looking for advice on insulating a stand-alone studio... I want to keep the "exposed" studs look (similar to board & batten). I plan on installing rigid insulation between the studs, offset by 3/4 inch strips. Will I have any issues with condensation with this plan?

[image]

Comment: Why are you going to the effort of making all those 3/4" spacers and air gaps? You're getting less insulation for more work. Put in an extra 1-1/2" of insulation to keep the shed super warm, or just push the insulation against the outer wall and put your ship lap directly against that. If you want a shallower reveal, put in one piece of wood spacer instead of 2 and save yourself a lot of cutting & installation time.

Comment: FreeMan.. Thx.. Will a vapor barrier be necessary?

Comment: That I'll leave to those who understand the concepts better. Is the building heated?

Comment: Most of the time, no

Comment: Here is a good resource for understanding the need for a vapor barrier.  https://www.certainteed.com/insulation/resources/do-i-need-vapor-barrier/#:~:text=A%20vapor%20retarder%20is%20a,the%20wall%20you're%20insulating.

Comment: JRaef... Good ino... Thx